# SharePoint WebService: Get List Item Navigation URL

Tags: web-services

I'm using the sharepoint's web service (GetListItems) method to get some fields data for list's items, now in addition for the information that i retrieve for an item **I need its direct URL**, so i can give the user an optional link to click in order to navigate smoothly to that item in the sharepoint website

Here is my code that gets the item's data:

```
XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
XmlNode ndViewFields =
    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
XmlNode ndQueryOptions =
    xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

var cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
      new Uri(url),
      "NTLM",
      new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain));
SPListWebService.Credentials = cc;
SPListWebService.Url = url + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";


//Query Options Node
ndQueryOptions.InnerXml =
    "<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>" +
    "<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>";
//Qyery node
foreach (DataRow row in view.Rows)
{
    string v = row[ffdmn].ToString();
    ndQuery.InnerXml = string.Format("<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='{0}'/>" +
   "<Value Type='Text'>{1}</Value></Eq></Where>", sfdmname, v);

    XmlNode ndListItems =
        SPListWebService.GetListItems(listName, null, ndQuery,
        ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);

    foreach (XmlNode node in ndListItems.ChildNodes)
    {
        if (node.Name == "rs:data")
            foreach (XmlNode innerNode in node.ChildNodes)
                if (innerNode.Name == "z:row")
                {
                   //I do some logic here to get the targeted fields
                }
    }
}
```

Any help?

(Also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639250/sharepoint-webservice-get-list-item-navigation-url))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `ows_EncodedAbsUrl` (document libraries have a correct url, but lists do not):

```
http://server/sites/SiteCollection/SubSite/Lists/My%20List/4_.000
```

Then, do a little string manipulation to get a valid URL:

```
http://server/sites/SiteCollection/SubSite/Lists/My%20List/DispForm.aspx?ID=4
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you build a new URL by string replacement on the existing path to the web service (which you know).